# hibernate.MappingException persistent class not known

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have this exception :

> org.hibernate.MappingException: persistent class not known:
>   java.lang.Long

I'm using Hibernate 5.1.0.Final and spring-orm 4.2.4.RELEASE

My spring configuration file (`spring.xml`) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/ecollection" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
<bean id="hibernateAnnotatedSessionFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.ecollection.model.Adresse</value>
            <value>com.ecollection.model.Utilisateur</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>
<bean id="utilisateurDao" class="com.ecollection.dao.UtilisateurDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateAnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="adresseDao" class="com.ecollection.dao.AdresseDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateAnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

And I have two MySQL tables, `User` and `Address`.

```
User = Id, Name and Firstname
Address = Id, Street, City and UserId
```

for UserId in my Address entitybean, I'm doing this :

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
public Long getIdUtilisateur() {
    return idUtilisateur;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not use a **non entity** as a target for `OneToOne` or `JoinColumn`, as you did here:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
public Long getIdUtilisateur() {
    return idUtilisateur;
}
```

Instead you can use this approach for mapping `Utilisateur` and `Address` relationship:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
public Utilisateur getUtilisateur() {
    return utilisateur;
}
```

Of course, `Utilisateur` should be an entity:

```
@Entity
public class Utilisateur { ... }
```

Comment: Oh ! I understand ! I will try it. Thanks !